# How to check duplicate column name in a row and delete second row which has the same class_name

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a school registration system where students can add and delete classes for more php practice

for example, a student has 2 Accounting 101 classes added to his/her schedule which should not happen.

How can i check my rows where if Accounting 101 occured twice in class schedule 
and delete the second entry which is a duplicate automatically

for example my current schedule:
my Table

```
ticket   class_name      days    start_hours  end_hours  units   room_number   instructor_name
1094     Accounting 101  SAT     9:00 am 12:15 pm    5   CS266   HARMON , KAREN
2077     Accounting 101  M,W     5:00 pm 8:00 pm     5   SF103   SMITH,  BOB
```

I want to delete the second duplicated automatically because ticket 1094 is Accounting 101
I wrote the code to add and delete classes but I want to prevent from duplicate class_name to be added or
it should be deleted

how can I write my query for this.

Thanks

Comment: do oyu temporarily add those records on the database or the subjects are only saved on the database adter it has been approved?

Comment: it has not been approved yet, the classes get added because of my code and saved to the database.  but after added I want it to find duplicated class names and delete the second entry automatically.  thanks

Comment: actually you can restrict the user from adding another class which already existed on the list by adding constraint. try this one, `ALTER  TABLE tableName ADD CONSTRAINT class_unique UNIQUE (class_name)` after that has been executed, try inserting duplicate record again.

Comment: do I put this ALTER table query after the class has been added?

Comment: no, execute that directly on mysql. It enforces a rule on the column to accept on unique value. can you give the table structure? so I can help you more with this `:)`

Comment: when you say table structure, whats on my phpmyadmin table?  thanks

Comment: yes, how you design your table where the class gets by the student added

Comment: $sql2 = "INSERT INTO register_classes(ticket, class_name, days, start_hours, end_hours, units, room_number, instructor_name, student_id, is_active, semester) 
 VALUES('$ticket', '$class_name', '$dbdays' , ' $start_hours' , ' $end_hours ' , ' $dbunits ' , ' $dbroomnumber', ' $dbinstructor', '$student_id', '1', '$semester')";

Comment: see my answer below `:)`

Comment: ok it worked!  I added this $alter = mysql_query("ALTER TABLE register_classes ADD CONSTRAINT reg_unique UNIQUE (class_name, student_id, semester)");  before inserting into database thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our conversation above, you can add a constraint so the table so a student can also insert *unique* `class_name` for every semester.

```
ALTER TABLE register_classes 
ADD CONSTRAINT reg_unique UNIQUE (class_name, student_id, semester)
```

once you have executed this, you are no longer allowed to have the same `class_name` on a student for a particular `semester`.

Comment: so I will add this code after the INSERT INTO register_classes right?  sorry about the confusion

Comment: ok it worked!  I added this $alter = mysql_query("ALTER TABLE register_classes ADD CONSTRAINT reg_unique UNIQUE (class_name, student_id, semester)");  before inserting into database thanks a lot

Comment: you don't need to execute the `ALTER` statement everytime you insert a record. `:)`

Comment: execute it once only, go to phpmyadmin then execute the `ALTER` statement query.

Answer (score 0):

When you insert records via form,first check if class name exists

```
$SQL = "SELECT * from student WHERE class_name = '".$_POST['class_name']."'";
```

Using this query, check whether any records exists. If so then delete previous one and add or simply get out of the condition.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a later ticket number means it was added later; the following query should return all the duplicates that need to be deleted.

```
SELECT *
FROM schedule s
WHERE s.ticket =  
    (SELECT MAX(s2.ticket) 
    FROM schedule s2
    WHERE s.class_name = s2.class_name
    GROUP BY s2.class_name, s2.student, s2.semester
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 1);
```

Though, as @JW pointed out, it might be better to catch these duplicates before even inserting them.

Comment: your right JW was right i add this code $alter = mysql_query("ALTER TABLE register_classes ADD CONSTRAINT reg_unique UNIQUE (class_name, student_id, semester)"); before inserting to database, so now duplicate classes wont be added.